# Flutter- how to download apk and install

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a .NetCore api which returns an apk file. I want to make a request to endpoint, download apk and install it. After I am getting response, I am creating the file like that:

```
var file = await File().writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
```

So, my questions is, what should be my output path to install it and how can I install the apk? I am doing this to update my app.

Comment: how u want to insatll apk ? from app that u download the apk?

Comment: @Jarvis098 Yes.